# C# Changing color of label based on trackbar value

Tags: c#, colors, trackbar

I am working with a trackbar that has a value of 0 to 100. In my code automatic = 0 that you see in the image below.

What i am trying to accomplish is that any number below 35 should change the labels (lableFS) forcolor to red, while any number above that should change the labels forecolor to green. I have that working fine, however the exception here should be that if the value of the trackbar is 0 or even if the labelFS text is set to "Automatic", then the labelFS forecolor should be black. Below is a gif image that will show you exactly what i mean, as well as my current code.

Thank you in advance for any help!

[image: Demonstration of my app]

I know its a simple issue, however i have tried numerous ways and i cant seem to find what is stopping it from changing to black.

```
        private void fanSlider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblFS.Text = "" + fanSlider.Value * 5;

        if (lblFS.Text == "0")
        {
            lblFS.Text = "Automatic";
        }

        int value;
        if (Int32.TryParse(lblFS.Text, out value))
        {
            if (value <= 35)
            {
                lblFS.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            if (value > 35)
            {
                lblFS.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

            }

            if (value == 0)
            {
                lblFS.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Use fanSlider.Value directly instead of inspecting the label text

Comment: Im going to go back and do that now, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening here is that whenever the bar is at 0 you set its text to `Automatic`, and then afterwards you try to change its color checking if its text is 0 but since you have already changed it to `Automatic` the condition will always be false...

Try this:

```
private void fanSlider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblFS.Text = "" + fanSlider.Value * 5;
    if (lblFS.Text == "0")
    {
        lblFS.Text = "Automatic";
        lblFS.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }
    int value;
    if (Int32.TryParse(lblFS.Text, out value))
    {
        if (value <= 35)
        {
            lblFS.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        if (value > 35)
        {
            lblFS.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's about what I figured, i guess i have a mental block right now and couldn't find out where it was happening. Anyways this worked and thank you for the help!

Comment: @user3627587 Pleasure to help... :) Sometimes this happens to me too, very silly small mistakes take my time and I keep try to find the mistake but I can not and when I find it next day, I say damn! :P 
If this helped please select it as answer and upvote it.